# How to make the watcher saga fire a worker saga only on the first dispatch on an action pattern?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, react-redux-i18n

How to make the watcher saga fire a worker saga only on the first dispatch on an action pattern?

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(CHATBOT.START, handleChatbotLoad); //I want watcher saga to trigger handleChatbotLoad only on the very first dispatch of CHATBOT.START
    yield takeEvery(CONVERSATION.ADD_QUERY, handleUserInput);
}
```

So ya, I want watcher saga to trigger handleChatbotLoad only on the very first dispatch of CHATBOT.START. I can have a flag in the state like `started` and dispatch CHATBOT.START only once.
But then I was expecting a method like `takeFirst` or something like that. Is there any such method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args) (or [spawn](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#spawnfn-args), [fork](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#forkfn-args)) some function in root saga, which means it'll be called only once when app started. And  use [take](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takepattern) in this function to wait for action dispatched:

```
function* onlyVeryFirstStartWatcher() {
    const action = yield take(CHATBOT.START);
    // started, do stuff...
    yield call(handleChatbotLoad);
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(CONVERSATION.ADD_QUERY, handleUserInput);
  yield call(onlyVeryFirstStartWatcher)
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna call handleChatbotLoad when the app starts. I want is the handleChatbotLoad to be called only on the first dispatch of CHATBOT.START. I tried what u mentioned above, ```function* chatbotStartWatcher() {
    yield take(CHATBOT.START, handleChatbotLoad);
}

function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(CONVERSATION.ADD_QUERY, handleUserInput);
    yield call(chatbotStartWatcher);
}

export default rootSaga;``` but ```handleChatbotLoad``` is called on every dispatch on ```CHATBOT.START```

Comment: @PraveenDass no need to pass `handleChatbotLoad` as second param of `take`. Just call it after. I updated the answer.